# Success callback on $http.post in AngularJS using Firefox

Tags: ajax, angularjs, post, cors

I have a simple CORS AJAX call from within AngularJS application with success callback:

```
$http({method:'POST',url:"http://0.0.0.0:4567/authenticate", 
 params: {Lusername:scope.Lusername,Lpassword:scope.Lpassword}})
 .success(function(){alert("Success")})
```

When used in Safari it works fine: returns expected JSON object and shows the alert box. However in Firefox, although the JSON object is returned properly the success callback is not triggered.

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you a jsFiddle which can reproduce the problem ? By the way, I know that's just for the example, but contemplate to use $window.alert() rather than just alert() (where [$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$window) is a service that you inject).

Comment: Possibility of CORS. Check for that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you handle the OPTIONS request in the server. If it returns 404 then Firefox wont call the next request (in your case the POST mentioned above).

Comment: What if I have no access to the server options :)

Comment: CORS needs to be setup on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with last version of AngularJS:

```
$http.post("http://0.0.0.0:4567/authenticate", {
  Lusername: $scope.Lusername, 
  Lpassword: $scope.Lpassword
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   alert("Success");
});
```

Comment: This does not explain the problem or help anyone else who might have a similar problem in the future.